# Mui TextField placeholder is displayed with value on first refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I'm getting this weird behavior that I don't know how to solve, on edit mode of this form if I refresh the page I get a bug where both the value and the placeholder are displayed in the field

-- This is my form component

```js
const Form = () => {
  // fetch hook to get the settings data.
  const settings = useGetSettingsQuery();
  // initialize the useFormik hook with the data just fetched
  const form = useSettingsForm({ initialValues: settings.data?.data ?? {} });

  return (
    <Box>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
         <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            name={'id'}
            label={'id'}
            placeholder={'ticket id'}
            variant="outlined"
            value={form.values.id}
            onChange={form.handleChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          initial values
          <pre>{JSON.stringify({ id: form.initialValues.id }, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          current value values
          <pre>{JSON.stringify({ id: form.values.id }, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

-- and this is my hook, right now I've deleted everything in my hook, and this is what's left:

```js
export const useSettingsForm = ({ initialValues }: Props) => {
  return useFormik<Partial<ISetting>>({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: {
      ...initialValues,
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({}),
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      console.log('submitted -> ', values);
    },
  });
};
```

the current behavior

[image]

---

For my `useGetSettings` hook, I'm using RTK query to fetch the data and handle the server state, this is the a snippet of `apiSlice`:

```js
export const settingApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints(builder) {
    return {
      getSettings: builder.query<IGetSettingsResp, void>({
        query() {
          return `/setting`;
        },
        providesTags: ['setting'],
      }),
    };
  },
});

export const { useGetSettingsQuery } = settingApiSlice;
```

---

as you can see in the picture the placeholder text and value are displayed, is there any way to fix this bug, thank you

Comment: Can you show what `settings` is initially and perhaps output the `useGetSettingsQuery` hook contents?

Comment: for the settings at first time it's empty (empty object) then when the data is fetched it gets reinitialized again with the new data, I've updated the question with more snippets.
thank you @WesleyLeMahieu

Comment: Thank you. I apologize it was not necessary. I see the issue though is with the id. Check my revised answer.

Comment: I apologize  @WesleyLeMahieu, I've made a mistake in the pasting of the input to the question, in my code I'm using the name='id' as you suggested, and it's still the same issue.

I also have this same issue with all of the other fields that I've on the same page

I've  updated the question with the right name

Answer (score 0):

In `Formik`, the `name` of the input ties into the `property` of it's value inside of `form.values`. So this:

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  name={'ticket number'}
  label={'ticket number'}
  placeholder={'ticket number'}
  variant="outlined"
  value={form.values.id}
  onChange={form.handleChange}
/>
```

Should be this:

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  name="id"
  label={'ticket number'}
  placeholder={'ticket number'}
  variant="outlined"
  value={form.values.id}
  onChange={form.handleChange}
/>
```

When you use `name={'ticket number'}` (or `name="ticket number"`), it's literally trying to set the value on `form.values.ticket number` instead of `form.values.id`, as you want it to be since that's your `value`.

The `id` in `value={form.values.id}` is connected to `name="id"`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a defaultValue will solve the problem, at least it solved in my case.

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        value={salary}
                        label= "Blah Blah Blah..."
                        variant="outlined"
                        type="number"
                        inputProps={{ min: 0 }}
                        onChange={(e) => setSalary(parseInt(e.target.value, 10))}
                        required
                    />
                </Grid>
```

This is my code and it's output looks like this:
[image]

When I add the defaultValue={0} part, the code look like this:
[image]

I am a newbie in React field and therefore, following explanation is totaly my own idea, I literally think this way but I am not sure if it's true. I assume this problem is caused because the React tries to load the Texfield and it fails loading the value since the value hasn't been loaded into the state and the label is loaded into where it normally belongs (inside the text field) but If you provide a defaultValue, it will display the label as it should (on the top of the text field).